# c# receive text file(s) located in documents directory, then send text file with API

Tags: c#, php

Hello (sorry for my bad English), so basically i'm creating a simple **c#** application that retrieves `.txt` files located within the documents directory. My program is going to allow users to open these text files and edit them, then upload to my website.

the text files i'm looking to retrieve are located in this path:

```
Libraries -> Documents -> XYZtxtMapper -> Savedstuff -> example.txt
```

I'm looking for some sort of way in **c#** to receive the example.txt file within the path shown above, once I've retrieved the example.txt file i would call a API on my server, example:

```
var client = new WebClient()) 
client.DownloadString("https://example.com/file=" + example.txt); //<- Calls my API
```

Once the above is called i would use **PHP** to `$_GET['file']`, then what **PHP** code would i use to upload the txt file that i use `$_GET['file']` to my server? Could i use `fwrite()` to upload the file to my server (website)?

Sorry for my bad English and me being a noob! I'm still pretty new to all this programming stuff

Comment: What's your question, it's not clear. Also if you want to transfer a whole file, it's better to go for POST

Comment: So you want when server get `$_GET['file'] = "example.txt"`, it send back string to your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your English make your explain not very well. As I understand, you want use a C# app to send a string to your server via `GET` method, then get it's response, right?

Then if you use WebClient:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string yourString = File.ReadAllText("C:\\path\\toYourFile.txt"); // Read file content
// string yourString = "C:\\path\\toYourFile.txt"; // Or you want send filename
string response = wc.DownloadString("https://example.com/pathTo/yourPHPFile.php?file=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(yourString));
```

Note: You have to include `pathto/yourPHPFile.php?file=` to your URL, where `pathto/yourPHPFile.php` is your php file, `?` is the begin your query. If you unfamily with this, read more about PHP GET